# Fix "NASM error: Invalid combination of opcode and operands" for add on Real Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, real-mode

I want to increase the DS Register by 200h on Real Mode but it gives me the "invalid combination of opcode" error when doing it like:

```
add ds,200h
```

I tried with ax and there was no problem. I guess that it happens because the ds register itself but I have no explanation for this.

It's not like I MUST do it that way, I fixed it by doing this instead:

```
mov  ax,200h
mov  ds,ax
```

But I would like to know the exact reason for this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When in doubt, consult the instruction set reference. You will see that there is simply no version of `add` that operates on segment registers. The exact reason is that. The engineers who created the x86 instructions didn't provide such a version.

Comment: Where can I consult this reference? @Jester

Comment: [Official pdf version](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm), [online conversion](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `add` operation cannot be used on the segment registers including `DS`. The difference is that `AX` is a general purpose register and thus a different set of instructions, including `add` is available for that register.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> add ds,200h
> ```
>
> I fixed it by doing this instead:
>
> ```
> mov  ax,200h
> mov  ds,ax
> ```

That replacement code will **not have raised the `DS` segment register by 200h**!

The correct sequence is:

```
mov     ax, ds        ; Tranfer (copy) to a general purpose register
add     ax, 0200h     ; Do the arithmatic on that one
mov     ds, ax        ; Transfer the result back
```

The only instructions that deal directly with a segment register like `DS` are:

```
push    ds
pop     ds
mov     ds, register/memory     e.g. mov ds, dx
mov     register/memory, ds     e.g. mov [bp+2], ds
lds     register, memory        e.g. lds si, [bx]
```

Comment: Yes, I know it does not do that... But since It was originally 0 I was able to just pass the result without any problem. Anyway, thanks for your answer.